# Meteor App: Push notifications stopped working for Android 8+ when updating TargetSDK to 26

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, amazon-sns, phonegap-plugin-push

### Context:

- Meteor `1.8.0.1`
- Cordova `6.4.0` (included with Meteor)
- phonegap-plugin-push `1.11.1` (last version which supports GCM)
- Push notifications via Amazon SNS -> GCM

### Problem:

Recently we had to update our `targetSdkVersion` from `25` to `26`, because of new restrictions of the Google Play Store.
Since we did that, our push notifications stopped working for devices with Android `8` and above.

Registering the device works fine, but it just won't receive any notifications.

Tested with following devices:

- Samsung Galaxy S9+ Android `8` -> does **not** work
- Sony Xperia XZ Premium Android `9` -> does **not** work
- Google Nexus 7 (2013) Android `6.0.1` -> works fine

### Notes:

I tried to use a newer version of phonegap-plugin-push (`2.1.3` the last one which supports Cordova `6.4.0`) with a firebase test project, from which I got the `google-service.json`, so I can use fcm but that even caused the app to crash.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [post](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels). Starting from Android 8 all notifications have to have notification channel.

Comment: That's right - problem is, that phonegap-plugin-push does not support channels until version 2, which won't support gcm anymore

Comment: Does that mean, I have to build different versions for Android < 8 and Android > 8 to support this?